# Can't access mamp server with internal IP

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, mac, localhost, mamp

Running MAMP 2.1.1 on my 10.7.2 OS X Mac Pro. I can access server if I choose a port (such as the default 8888) but changing it to port 80 causes it to not work, except with `localhost`.

This used to work before! I was running MAMP with virtualhosts such as `mysite.dev` and accessing them just fine, and others on the internal network could access my computer with my IP, but now it seems to have broken down. I do not know what I did to cause it to stop functioning unfortunately, as I believe it to be something that happened several days ago.

I have tried a lot of stuff such as:

- Restarting computer
- Reinstalling MAMP
- Switching IP address
- Making sure no other apache is running by killing all httpd processes
- Changing permissions for the apache logs
- Removing all virtualhost functionality
- Resetting /etc/hosts file to default (as you can tell I was getting desperate)

Basically I feel like the main symptom is that I cannot access my MAMP server with my local address (even on my own computer!) by writing `192.168.1.X` in the browser.

I need to be able to access local sites without a custom port `:8888`. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key turned out to be that pow (http://pow.cx/) had been installed and had forwarded all port 80 traffic to port 20559! For some reason I did not have `/sbin`in my PATH which caused all calls to `ipfw`to fail.

I had already uninstalled it but removed the port problem now using `ipfw`

Solution was to remove the port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have another process running that binds to that port (but doesn't bind to localhost). Use netstat to find out which process is binding that port.

Skype can usually be at fault (don't ask me why), at least on Windows. Not sure about OS X.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Closing down Skype did not work however. netstat is not providing any clues. 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.1.X still return junk while localhost works as intended.